# Can we tell Vision to group horizontally line by line?

Tags: google-vision

Following this official [sample](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/fulltext-annotations), the OCR is not grouping the words into correct **Paragraphs**:

[image]

Is there any way to tell Vision group them line by line horizontally as below?

[image]